# javascript - reduce video size(resolution/quality/file size) before uploading to server

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video-processing

I want to reduce the file size before the user uploads it since the internet speed in my clients area is less but the computer is quite well.

It takes forever to upload only 12 MB of video.
So I want to reduce the size of the video on client side for faster upload.

Someone please help me with this, I don't have any experience with javascript video handling.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress a video on client side web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316791/compress-a-video-on-client-side-web)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't solve the problem
Thank you

Comment: It's not really possilbe at the moment make your users upload videos they have compressed themselve

Comment: You need to find a Javascript-based data compressor (for some formats like Gzip or Bzip2). When a user uploads a file, your code passes the bytes through the compressor's functions then sends to server... See [**these benchmarks**](https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO) for good algorithms. For example research [**Bzip2 compressors**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&source=hp&ei=SrScW6aXNInzkwW054agCA&q=javascript+bzip2+compressor)